# Postgresql / Timescaledb ERROR: Deprecated trigger function should not be invoked

Tags: postgresql, time-series, timescaledb

I work with postgresql boosted with timescaledb fork (pretty impressed with its performance while it worked ;)
I got a script that downloads data, modifies it and puts into a csv file.
Then a psql script is invoked to create a temp table that inserts data into the database

```
psql -U postgres -d q1 -c "CREATE TABLE tmpp (time bigint NOT NULL, ask real NOT NULL, bid real NOT NULL)"
psql -U postgres -d q1 -c "\copy tmpp (time, ask, bid) from '/sth/sth.csv' delimiter ',' CSV"
psql -U postgres -d q1 -c "insert into realfun select * from tmpp"
psql -U postgres -d q1 -c "DROP TABLE tmpp"
```

Funny thing is, that it worked for me before, but now I got an error :

```
ERROR:  Deprecated trigger function should not be invoked
```

I must have messed up sth, but cant figure out what it is [how original]
I will be happy to provide more details, if needed
I cannot find anything similar in google, please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that you have a newer shared library version than the extension version you have installed (Timescale is an extension, not a fork). You can fix this with `ALTER EXTENSION timescaledb UPDATE`.
 The alter command is [documented here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-alterextension.html).